# Mapquest Open Aerial new tile server url?

Tags: mapquest

The MapQuest page for [open aerial api](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map) states that the url will be depreciated on Feb 15, 2013 and no longer work.  The page does not list the new URL!!!  Anyone know where to find this info?  Mapquest??  anyone?

```
Alert:
The tile URL for the Open Aerial Tiles has changed. Please be aware that accessing
tiles through the oatile subdomain is deprecated and http://oatile1.mqcdn.com/ 
will be  unavailable after February 15, 2013.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new URL is listed further down on the page; basically oatile1 has changed to otile1, so that the URL is more consistent with URL used for the MapQuest Open Map Tiles.

Here's an example URL for an Open Aerial Tile:
http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/15/5240/12661.jpg

If you change ..../sat/... to .../map/... in the URL, you'll get the Open Map Tile for that specific area.

Comment: I see now...subtle change that I didn't notice.  thnks